# back time i used android studio fine but after while i have open software i got theses error

Tags: android, android-studio

An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that
   depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
   Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-33.

   Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
   plugin 7.4.1 is 33.

   Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
   plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
   compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
   allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
   targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
   minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
   on).

im trying to build my code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lower library version to 1.7.2 will work:

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.7.2")
```

Reference revision [1.8.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.8.0-alpha01):

> Note: This version will only compile against the Android 14 (Upside
> Down Cake) Developer Preview 1 SDK.